# How to keep all the textbox values and dropdownlist selected values even after page refresh in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I've 20 TextBoxes and 16 dropdownlists in my form. My problem is when i refresh the page it's clearing all the fields. I've an idea to keep the vales in session but, the code is going to be lengthy. Is there any other solution rather than this>

Comment: Have you considered localstorage/sessionstorage?

Answer (score 0):

a) If it's a webform application you could consider activating viewstate. It keeps the state of the input fields beyond postbacks. It will loose the state if you refresh the page with pressing F5 or navigating back and forth though.

b) You could store the data from your input fields into a server side session object and populate the input fields on page load. If the session object is there populate and fields, if not, then don't

c) you could use localStorage or sessionStorage on the client side to store the field values. With the help of jQuery it is quite easy to grab all input fields from a form and store each input value as a Key/Value object (where the key is the ID of the input field) into the localStorage or sessionStorage as json representation. On `document.ready` you could check for the existance of such an object in the storage and populate the fields accordingly. The difference of localStorage and sessionStorage is that sessionStorage is valid for the actual session only and its content is lost when you close your browser and/or tab. If you need a longer term storage which is valid across tabs and sessions you might want to use localStorage

I hope this helps you finding the right option for you.